# Making posts inactive after a date and time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rails-activejob

I've to make posts inactive after a given date and time by the user who creates these posts. I've added a boolean field "published" to make a post active or unactive.

If the post is active, every visitor will see the post. If it's inactive, the post will be seen in the user dashboard as inactive.

For you guys what is the best way to make a post inactive after the given datetime passed? That should be automatic but I don't think the suitable way is using Active Job and ;

- Check all posts in the db if active,
- If active, compare the given datetime and current datetime
- If needed, make it inactive

I'm using heroku, so that'll make my worker busy all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some things:

**Option 1:**

Based in the @jawad-khawaja answer, I think a better approach is to use `expired_at` instead of `published_at` because for me, a publish date is a date when a post is available for people. This way the user can define an expiration date for his own post (not the same publish date).

Here some example how to you can get active/inactive posts based on its expiration date

```
# active posts
scope :published, -> { where('expired_at > ?', Time.now) }

# inactive posts
scope :unpublished, -> { where('expired_at < ?', Time.now) }
```

**Option 2:**

If you have an attribute `published` as boolean and you really need mark it automatically, the option is to use [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

**CONS** for this option:

- You will have two attributes representing the same thing: `published` as boolean and `expiration_datetime` as datetime
- If the minimum unit for an expiration date is a minute, you need to check every minute if every *not-expired* post enter to the expired state. And you will have probably an overload for your server.

**Conclusion:**

My recommended way is to choose the option 1.

Comment: Option 1 seems more suitable now. I think I'll let user to specify an expiration date and time while he creates the post, and I'll write this to a field called expire_at. While I'm listing the posts in the views, I can use this scopes. But still the same question, every user will create about 10 posts every week. 300 users will use the app, every month 12 000 posts will be created. And I'll never delete them until the user deletes the post himself. Is this way good enough from the performance point of view?

Comment: It depends, if you have 1 million of posts you don't want to show all of them at once. In this case you would want to use pagination, filter, etc. In terms of databases most of them can store a lot of data without loose performance.

Answer (score 3):

If you simply plan to fetch and display posts, rather than setting the boolean value, you could just add a scope to the model:

```
scope :published, -> { where('publish_at < ?', Time.now) }
```

And use like this `Post.published`

Let me know if this helps.

Update 1:

If you need to determine if a post is active or not, add a method to the model like this,

```
def active?
    self.publish_at < Time.now
end
```

Comment: Good idea. For active posts, other functions will be available like making a  payment etc.. I was thinking to keep both active and inactive posts in the same table, and differ them with a boolean value. But is it good enough for the performance view to do something like : current_user.posts.published? That will query thousands of posts and find the published one depending on the scope ?

Comment: what happens with inactive post? there is no way to identify them.

Comment: @EnisD. with the boolean column, you would still require a scope to fetch those records where the value is true. Also, with my method there is the added benefit of avoiding the need to set the boolean field in the database at specific times.